# Close dialog after submitting in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a list of files and in the end of each li-element I got a button, which looks like

```html
<a href="/urlToDialogView/" data-rel="dialog"><div class="settingsBtn"></div></a>
```

In the dialog I got a form. A want to submit some data and then close dialog. To be honest I think I'm missing something simple, the submit works but I don't want to load any html data on the php side, I just want to close the dialog.

I accomplished this but enable ajaxform plugin and I handle it manually:

```
$(document).delegate("#myDialog", "pageinit", function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function() {
            $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');        
        }
        }); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

But it seems like a wrong solution. I don't have an ajax loader picture, and the jquery mobile framework has everything for ajax handling, but I didn't find how to close the dialog =(

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.